# Can't save vehicle info to firebase [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am taking a Udemy course on building an Uber app. I have created a dart file called VehicleInfo.dart which can be seen below. For some reason none of my Vehicle Info is saving to firebase. If anyone could help/point out where I may be making a mistake I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance :) below this code is my signuppage.dart file as well. After the user signs up, they are then taken to the vehicle info page. Below that is the unhandled exception error I am getting as well.

**vehicleinfo.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/BrandColors.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/globalvariables.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/screens/mainpage.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/widgets/BrandButton.dart';

class VehicleInfo extends StatelessWidget {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  void showSnackBar(title, context) {
    final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        title,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  static const String id = 'vehicleinfo';

  var vehicleMakeController = TextEditingController();
  var vehicleModelController = TextEditingController();
  var vehicleColorController = TextEditingController();
  var vehicleLicensePlateController = TextEditingController();
  var driverLicenseIDNumberController = TextEditingController();

  void updateProfile(context){
    String id = currentFirebaseUser.uid;
    DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('drivers/$id/Vehicle_Details');

    Map map = {
      'Vehicle Make': vehicleMakeController.text,
      'Vehicle Model': vehicleModelController,
      'Vehicle Color': vehicleColorController,
      'Vehicle License Plate': vehicleLicensePlateController,
      'Driver License ID Number': driverLicenseIDNumberController,
    };

    driverRef.set(map);

    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainPage.id, (route) => false);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 20,),

              Image.asset('./images/Sign_In_Logo.png', height: 110, width: 110,),
              
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,20,20,30),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    Text('Enter Vehicle Details',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 22),),

                    SizedBox(height: 25,),

                    // Vehicle Make
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: vehicleMakeController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Vehicle Make',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        )
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    // Vehicle Model
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: vehicleModelController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Vehicle Model',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          )
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    // Vehicle Color
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: vehicleColorController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Vehicle Color',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          )
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    // Vehicle License Plate Number
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: vehicleLicensePlateController,
                      maxLength: 11,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterText: '',
                          labelText: 'Vehicle License Plate',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          )
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    // Driver License ID Number
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: driverLicenseIDNumberController,
                      //keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Driver License ID Number',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          )
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 40,),

                    BrandButton(
                      color: BrandColors.colorPrimary,
                      title: 'Register Vehicle',
                      onPressed: (){
                        if(vehicleMakeController.text.length < 3){
                          showSnackBar('Please provide a valid vehicle make', context);
                          return;
                        }

                        if(vehicleModelController.text.length < 2){
                          showSnackBar('Please provide a valid vehicle model', context);
                          return;
                        }

                        if(vehicleColorController.text.length < 3){
                          showSnackBar('Please provide a valid vehicle model', context);
                          return;
                        }

                        if(vehicleLicensePlateController.text.length < 5){
                          showSnackBar('Please provide a valid license plate', context);
                          return;
                        }

                        if(driverLicenseIDNumberController.text.length <9){
                          showSnackBar('Please provide a valid driver id number', context);
                          return;
                        }

                        updateProfile(context);


                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**signuppage.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/BrandColors.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/globalvariables.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/screens/loginpage.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/screens/mainpage.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/screens/vehicleinfo.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/widgets/ProgressDialog.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/widgets/SkapeButton.dart';
import 'package:cab_driver/widgets/showsnackbar.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {

  static const String id = 'signup';

  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var _fullNameController = TextEditingController();
  var _emailController = TextEditingController();
  var _phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  var _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  var _confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  void signUpUser() async {

    String authErrMsg;

    // Show Please Wait Dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ProgressDialog(status: 'Signing you in...',),
    );

    try {
      //final
      User newUser = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      )).user;

      // Check if user registration success
      print('The new user:\n$newUser');
      Navigator.pop(context);
      if(newUser != null){
        showSnackBar('Registration Successful!', context);
        print('Registration Successful!');

        DatabaseReference newUserRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('drivers/${newUser.uid}');

        // Prepare data to be saved on users table
        Map userMap = {
          'fullname': _fullNameController.text,
          'email': _emailController.text,
          'password': _passwordController.text,
          'cellphone': _phoneNumberController.text,
        };

        newUserRef.set(userMap);

        currentFirebaseUser = newUser;

        // Take user to main page
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, VehicleInfo.id);
      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        authErrMsg = 'The password provided is too weak';
        print(authErrMsg);
        showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        authErrMsg = 'An account already exists for that email';
        print(authErrMsg);
        showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
      } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
        authErrMsg = 'Email address is invalid';
        print(authErrMsg);
        showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      showSnackBar(e, context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        BackButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainPage.id, (route) => false);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Image(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 150.0,
                      width: 150.0,
                      image: AssetImage('./images/Sign_In_Logo.png'),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 5,),

                    Text('Landscaper Sign Up',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[

                          // Full Name
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _fullNameController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                                labelText: 'Full Name',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                ),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                )
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(height: 10,),

                          // Email Address
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _emailController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Email Address',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                ),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                )
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(height: 10,),

                          // Phone Number
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _phoneNumberController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Phone Number',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.local_phone_outlined),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                ),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                )
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(height: 10,),

                          // Password
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                ),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                )
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(height: 10,),

                          // Confirm Password
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _confirmPasswordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                ),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                )
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                          ),

                          SizedBox(height: 20,),

                          BrandButton(
                            title: 'SIGN UP',
                            color: BrandColors.colorPrimary,
                            onPressed: () async {

                              String authErrMsg;

                              var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
                              if(connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.mobile && connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi){
                                authErrMsg = 'No Internet Connection';
                                print(authErrMsg);
                                showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
                              }
                              if (_passwordController.text != _confirmPasswordController.text) {
                                authErrMsg = 'Passwords Do Not Match';
                                print(authErrMsg);
                                showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
                              } else if (_fullNameController.text.length < 3){
                                authErrMsg = 'Please Provide A Valid Full Name';
                                print(authErrMsg);
                                showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
                              } else if (_phoneNumberController.text.length < 10){
                                authErrMsg = 'Please Provide A Valid Phone Number';
                                print(authErrMsg);
                                showSnackBar(authErrMsg, context);
                              } else {
                                signUpUser();
                              }
                              // signUpUser();
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginPage.id, (route) => false);
                      },
                      child: Text.rich(
                        TextSpan(
                          text: 'Already a Driver? ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Color(0xFF96A13A),
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',),
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: 'Log in',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    color: Color(0xFF96A13A),
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Unhandled Exception:**

```
    flutter: Registration Successful!
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController'
#0      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:403:7)
#1      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:400:9)
#2      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#3      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:398:13)
#4      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:400:9)
#5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#6      StandardMessageCodec.writeValue (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:398:13)
#7      StandardMethodCodec.encodeMethodCall (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:535:18)
#8      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:150:13)
#9      Meth<…>
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the code block below:

```dart
    Map map = {
          'Vehicle Make': vehicleMakeController.text,
          'Vehicle Model': vehicleModelController,
          'Vehicle Color': vehicleColorController,
          'Vehicle License Plate': vehicleLicensePlateController,
          'Driver License ID Number': driverLicenseIDNumberController,
    };
```

You're passing the `TextEditingController` instance for vehicle model, vehicle color, vehicle license plate and driver license id number.

You need to use the `.text` getter to get the actual string from the controllers.
Also, specifying the Map types will help you identify the errors next time.

Update the definition for `map` above to the one below and it should fix the error:

```dart
    Map<String, String> map = {
          'Vehicle Make': vehicleMakeController.text,
          'Vehicle Model': vehicleModelController.text,
          'Vehicle Color': vehicleColorController.text,
          'Vehicle License Plate': vehicleLicensePlateController.text,
          'Driver License ID Number': driverLicenseIDNumberController.text,
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate it. This worked well!